# Why doesn't this battery explode?

Tags: batteries, speakers

So I know that it sounds very stupid, but I'm trying to test the limits of a 12 dollar bluetooth speaker.

I disassembled the whole speaker and replaced the original 3 watt speaker with a 70 watt one.

The circuit has a build-in 18000 mAh battery wich outputs 3.7 Volts.

When I play some music(via bluetooth) the speaker works as it does normally,obviously not as loud as when I connect it to my amplifier.

The battery *seems* to do fine too,as it doesn't get hot and doesn't seem to explode

So my question is why the battery doesn't do something?

**PS.I'm doing this outside!**

Comment: 70 W is only the maximum power of the speaker. The device is happy to drive just 3W into it.

Comment: @τεκ So even if I add 3 speakers to it, they would still work fine?

Comment: If you add 3 speakers *and keep the impedance as seen by the amplifier the same* it would be allright, and (just in case you you wonder) the total sound you get from the 4 speakers would probably the same as you got from one speaker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I disassembled the whole speaker and replaced the original 3 watt speaker with a 70 watt one.

Assuming the original amplifier and speaker were matched, your new speaker is being driven by a 3 W amplifier. It probably won't sound any louder. You can still only get 3 W audio output.

> The battery seems to do fine too,as it doesn't get hot and doesn't seem to explode. So my question is why the battery doesn't do something?

Because you are still operating within its design limits.

> So even if I add 3 speakers to it, they would still work fine?

It depends how you wire them. The amplifier will have a rating for the minimum impedance (resistance) it can drive.

- If you series connect the speakers the resistance will increase and the output power will decrease because the amplifier won't be able to drive as much current because the resistance of the load has increased. It will sound quieter.
- If you parallel the speakers the resistance will decrease and more current will flow. This will overload and overheat the amplifier which may burn out if it doesn't have thermal protection built-in.

The battery is unlikely to be overloaded to the point of overheating.

---

From the comments:

> I compared the two with a decibel meter and the 70 watt one is a little bit louder then the 3 watt one.

[image]

*Figure 1. Loudspeaker cut-away. Note the suspension around the edge of the cone and the corrugated suspension at the base of the cone. Both add stiffness. Also visible is the voicecoil inside the magnet slot. If the voicecoil is pulled too hard in it will crash against the bottom of the slot. If it is driven too far out some of the coil will be outside the magnetic field. Overdriving either way will cause distortion. Image source: [Cinema Sound](https://www.cinemasound.com/speaker-work-illuminated/image/).*

There could be a several factors at play here. The 70 W speaker may be more efficient than the small one and so it will convert electrical power into audio power more efficiently. The (presumably) larger cone diameter may also shift more air. Things like the strength of the magnets, the narrowness of the magnet slot for the voice-coil, etc., will all play a part.

> The big difference was in speaker qualtity the 70 watt one sounded like heaven and had a MUCH better bass while the 3 watt one performed not so well.

The 3 W speaker is probably being driven to its limit of travel and this introduces non-linearities which we hear as distortion. The 70 W speaker, driven by a 3 W amplifier, is nowhere near its limits so it performs without distortion. Bigger is better for bass but enclosure design is important.

Comment: I compared the two with a decibel meter and the 70 watt one is a little bit louder then the 3 watt one. The big difference was in speaker qualtity the 70 watt one sounded like heaven and had a MUCH beter bass while the 3 watt one performed not so well.

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer. See the update after your comment.

Comment: The 70 watt speaker is likely slightly louder due to having a slightly higher sensitivity, resulting in more sound output per watt of input power. In other words, the amplifier is likely providing about the same amount of power to the 70 W speaker, but the 70 W speaker is a bit better at turning it into sound.